# Is there any way to operate on each element of multiple dataframes and then merge corresponding elements together in a new dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a new dataframe (mid) which calculates the average of each cell of the bid, ask dataframe.
The format of all three dataframes is the same.
How should I go about it?
I have read that one should not iterate over dataframes.
I've tried df.iterrows() but getting weird results.

This is the code so far

```
CDS_bid = {'Entity':['General Motors','Ford','Goldman Sachs','JPMC','Chevron'],
            '1YB':[14.39, 23.39, 17.51, 11.3, 4.38],
            '2YB':[33.97, 52.73, 24.02, 14.58, 9.63],
            '3YB':[59.05, 87.02, 33.01, 19.56, 17.62],
            '4YB':[85.94, 128.89, 43.39, 25, 25.88],
            '5YB':[116.66, 176.82, 56.74, 33.67, 32.98]
          }


CDS_ask = {'Entity':['General Motors','Ford','Goldman Sachs','JPMC','Chevron'],
            '1YA':[29.4, 45.49, 25.79, 19.53, 13.62],
            '2YA':[48.97, 72.6, 32.3, 22.54, 19.06],
            '3YA':[74.05, 106.89, 40.85, 27.08, 26.7],
            '4YA':[100.94, 146.62, 50.8, 32.09, 34.6],
            '5YA':[125.35, 186.82, 61.7, 37.7, 41.25]
          }

CDS_bid_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(CDS_bid)
CDS_ask_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(CDS_ask)
```

Need to create a new dataframe (mid) which calculates the average of each cell of the bid, ask dataframe.
Same format as bid, ask dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want, a few steps are needed:

1. Convert the dataframe values to a float
2. Set a common index and column values
3. Know how to do [subtraction](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html), addition and division of dataframes.

The code:

```
# When reading the dictionary to a dataframe,
# you should specify that your data is of type float,
# otherwise it will be an object (string).
CDS_bid_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(CDS_bid, dtype=float)
CDS_ask_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(CDS_ask, dtype=float)


# Set column Entity (which is still a string) as an index.
CDS_bid_df.set_index('Entity', inplace=True)
CDS_ask_df.set_index('Entity', inplace=True)


# The two dataframes have different columns, so one solution is to set the
# columns of the ask dataframe to the bid dataframe (or vice versa).
CDS_bid_df.columns = CDS_ask_df.columns

# Calculate the mid is now straightforward.
CDS_mid_df = CDS_bid_df.add(CDS_ask_df.sub(CDS_bid_df) / 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight on dtype, 
1) Index is lost - guess that has to be done for adding, 
more importantly 2) the col names have to be changed back

Comment: 2) Yes the col names can be changed back, but that's easy to do. 
For the new DF, since you are getting a mid (the new DF) and the col names for bid are different than the one from ask, then I don't know what idea for the col names you would want for the mid one.